# Quaternion-Based-Camera unwanted roll

Tags: c++, opengl, math, 3d, directx

I'm trying to implement a quaternion-based camera, but when moving around the X and Y axis, the camera produces an unwanted roll on the Z axis. I want to be able to look around freely on all axis.
I've read other topics about this problem (for example: http://www.flipcode.com/forums/thread/6525 ), but I'm not getting what is meant by "Fix this by continuously rebuilding the rotation matrix by rotating around the WORLD axis, i.e around <1,0,0>, <0,1,0>, <0,0,1>, not your local coordinates, whatever they might be."

```
//Camera.hpp
glm::quat rotation;

//Camera.cpp
void Camera::rotate(glm::vec3 vec)
{
    glm::quat paramQuat = glm::quat(vec);
    rotation = paramQuat * rotation;
}
```

I call the rotate function like this:

```
cam->rotate(glm::vec3(0, 0.5, 0));
```

This must have to do with local/world coordinates, right? I'm just not getting it, since I thought quaternions are always based on each other (thus a quaternion can't be in "world" or "local" space?).
Also, should i use more than one quaternion for a camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand it, and from looking at the code you provided, what they mean is that you shouldn't store and apply the rotation incrementally by applying rotate on the rotation quat all the time, but instead keeping track of two quaternions for each axis (X and Y in world space) and calculating the rotation vector as the product of those.

[edit: some added (pseudo)code]

```
// Camera.cpp
void Camera::SetRotation(glm::quat value)
{
    rotation = value;
}

// controller.cpp --> probably a place where you'd want to translate user input and store your rotational state
xAngle += deltaX;
yAngle += deltaY;
glm::quat rotationX = QuatAxisAngle(X_AXIS, xAngle);
glm::quat rotationY = QuatAxisAngle(Y_AXIS, yAngle);
camera.SetRotation(rotationX * rotationY);
```

Comment: Do you mean that in the rotate method, I'd have to split the glm::vec3 vec into an X and Y quaternion and then multiply each with a local X and Y quaternion in the camera class? How would I split this rotation?

Comment: I probably would just store a single rotation parameter in the camera class and keep the update logic in a controller (so you can also use the camera if you ever decide to create a pure flight controller etc, or you could use the same or similar controllers on regular objects in your scene). That would essentially replace the rotate method with a pure setter (see example code I edited in).

Comment: Thank you, the controller is a really good idea which I will implement for sure! Also, I finally got the rotations working. The goal was (for FPS cameras) to rotate the Y axis on the WORLD axis and the X axis on the local axis. This was mentioned in the other thread I posted, but took me some time to figure out what it really meant. Thanks!