# Unwanted Roll on FPS Camera

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, quaternions, glm-math

So just recently I've been learning to use quaternions, I got an fps camera going but I get some "unwanted" roll when rotating from the local **up** and **right** vectors, however I'm pretty sure this is normal, but how do I prevent it from doing that? I tried a few methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20855797/quaternion-based-camera-unwanted-roll) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30644/how-to-keep-my-quaternion-using-fps-camera-from-tilting-and-messing-up), both did not work and gave weird results when rotating the camera. Any help would be appreciated!

[Download Executable](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/236958465568800769/298691393428258816/OpenGLTest.zip)

```
void Transform::Update()
{
    transform = position * glm::toMat4(quatRot) * scale;
}

void Transform::ApplyRotation(glm::vec3 rot, bool isDegr = true)
{
    if (isDegr)
        quatRot = glm::quat(GetRads(rot)) * quatRot;
    else
        quatRot = glm::quat(rot) * quatRot;
}

glm::vec3 Transform::Forward() const
{
    return glm::normalize(glm::vec3(transform[2][0], transform[2][1], transform[2][2]));
}

glm::vec3 Transform::Right() const
{
    return glm::normalize(glm::vec3(transform[0][0], transform[0][1], transform[0][2]));
}

glm::vec3 Transform::Up() const
{
    return glm::normalize(glm::vec3(transform[1][0], transform[1][1], transform[1][2]));
}

void FPCamera::Update()
{
    Transform *trans = GetOwner()->GetTransform();

    Vec2_i difference = GetWindow()->GetDifference();

    glm::vec3 tmpDiff(-(static_cast<float>(difference[1]) * 0.5f), -(static_cast<float>(difference[0]) * 0.5f), 0.0f);

    trans->ApplyRotation(trans->Right() * tmpDiff[0]);
    trans->ApplyRotation(trans->Up() * tmpDiff[1]);

    view = glm::inverse(trans->GetMatrix());
}
```

Comment: normalize your vector

Comment: @TonyJ I assume you mean the `rot` parameter on `ApplyRotation`? I normalized it, but there will still be roll.

Comment: I would say run it through debugger, add some asserts to check if the vector is normalized. I can't say at which point the vector became not normalized without a minimal example, you need to figure that out. Also it's just a suggestion, not necessarily the problem, I just have seen enough bugs with vectors and quats when they are not normalized.

Comment: Have you compared your results to a reference implementation of matrix math functions like the [Sony Vector Math](https://github.com/erwincoumans/sce_vectormath) one?

Comment: I get why you would suggest it. I've never heard of it causing "bugs" when not normalized. I mean the worst it might do while thinking in my head is it may rotate by more of a multiple of `0.0f-1.0f`.

Comment: Also `isDegr` is defaulted to true, is rest of the code working in radiant or degrees?

Comment: @tadman Why, do you think GLM has errors in its math?

Comment: @TonyJ It's all in degrees except when used with rotational quaternions, or matrices. I use radians when using them.

Comment: @Karutoh I don't think it does, but you're writing your own Transform class here that might not be doing it correctly. It's very easy for `x[0][1]` to be mistakenly entered as `x[1][0]`.

Comment: @Tadman It's column-major I'm pretty sure it's correct. I mean otherwise I wouldn't be rotating in the right directions. Have you tried to run my executable? It wouldn't hurt to try though I suppose. Yeah no, lol. The way I had it was correct.

Comment: So Update() calculate transform using quatRot that was calculated in radians, but then you get the up and right vectors from the transform in degrees?

Comment: @TonyJ No wait this is correct. This is based off of local translation not rotation.

Comment: @Karutoh, You need to stop trying things, you should understand the problem first. Google how rotation is done.

Comment: @TonyJ Look I'm trying things to respect your answers. I don't just try them because I don't feel I have the knowledge. All I'm trying to do is prevent it from rolling. If there's more code that I need to show, let me know if this helps you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, when I used [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30644/how-to-keep-my-quaternion-using-fps-camera-from-tilting-and-messing-up) solution, I didn't know I needed to use world vectors instead of local vectors for the axis angles as I found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263325/3d-camera-has-unintended-roll?rq=1) solution.

```
void Transform::ApplyRotation(glm::quat yaw, glm::quat pitch)
{
    quatRot = pitch * quatRot * yaw;
}

void FPCamera::Update()
{
    Transform *trans = GetOwner()->GetTransform();

    Vec2_i difference = GetWindow()->GetDifference();

    glm::vec3 tmpDiff(-(static_cast<float>(difference[1]) * 0.5f), -(static_cast<float>(difference[0]) * 0.5f), 0.0f);

    trans->ApplyRotation(glm::quat(GetRads(glm::vec3(tmpDiff[0], 0.0f, 0.0f))), glm::quat(GetRads(glm::vec3(0.0f, tmpDiff[1], 0.0f))));

    view = glm::inverse(trans->GetMatrix());
}
```